# Не выполняется сложение с float

Tags: c++

Я выполняю сложение float + float. Мне надо в цикле прибавить к массиву типа `float` значение переменной `Eps=0.0001`. Вначале, когда числа равны целым, то все проходит нормально, но когда они становятся приблизительно равным `2309.786621`,то сложение не происходит.

```
    float Eps = 0.0001;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < unkPar; j++) {
            //нужное сложение
            w[j] += Eps;
            float temp = func(w[0], w[1], w[2], w[3], mX[i]);
            w[j] -= Eps;
            massJac[i][j] = (temp - func(w[0], w[1], w[2], w[3], mX[i])) / Eps;
        }
    }
}
```

В результате получается `0`,потому что `Eps` не добавляется. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Может у `float` просто точности не хватает? Попробуйте `double`.

Comment: Почему вы вообще используете в своей программе тип `float`? На это есть причины?

Answer (score 2):

Берем вашу константу и смотрим на фактическое значение переменной и следующее представимое значение в рамках IEEE754 `float`

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float f = 2309.786621f;
  printf("%.20f\n%.20f\n", f, nextafterf(f, FLT_MAX));
}
```

Получаем

```
2309.78662109375000000000
2309.78686523437500000000
```

То есть, во-первых, никакого `2309.786621` быть не может. Вы работатете с `2309.78662109375`. И ваше `0.0001` на самом деле является `0.0000999999974737875163555145263671875`.

И, во-вторых, следующее представимое значение отстоит от этого значения на `0.00024414062`. Следовательно сумма `2309.78662109375f` и `0.0001f` не представима в типе `float`. Сумма `2309.78662109375f + 0.0001f` должна либо округлиться назад к `2309.78662109375f`, либо вперед к `2309.786865234375f` - смотря что ближе. Очевидно `2309.78662109375f` все таки ближе. Поэтому никакого прибавления и не происходит.

Comment: `nextafter` это системная функция?

Comment: @Alexey Ismagilov: Это *стандартная* функция из стандартной библиотеки языка С (и, соотвественно, C++). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter